# Friend class not working

Tags: c++, class, private, friend

I am getting the typical '... is private within this context' error.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?
Code is shortened for readability.

in class SceneEditorWidgetController:
(settingsdialog and the variable used here is defined in the header)

```
SceneEditorPluginWidgetController::SceneEditorPluginWidgetController()
{
}
void SceneEditorPluginWidgetController::configured()
{
    priorKnowledge_setting = settingsDialog->priorKnowledgeProxyFinder->getSelectedProxyName().toStdString(); //This is the context
}
```

My class SettingsController.h

```
namespace Ui {
    class SettingsController;
}
namespace GuiController {
    class SettingsController : public QDialog
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        friend class SceneEditorPluginWidgetController;
    public:
        explicit SettingsController(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~SettingsController();

    private: //it is private here
        Ui::SettingsController* ui;
        IceProxyFinderBase* priorKnowledgeProxyFinder;
    };
}
```

I cannot modify the IceProxyFinderBase class, but it was used exactly (I'm probably blind?) like this before.

Could somebody please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is `SceneEditorPluginWidgetController` in the same namespace, `GuiController`? If not, then the unqualified `friend` declaration refers to a different class.

Comment: SceneEditorWidgetController is without a namespace, how would I declare that?

Comment: You mean it's in the global namespace? Qualify it as `::SceneEditorPluginWidgetController`.

Comment: Alright, I got it.
Thanks, sometimes you're just blind!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

With an unqualified class name, the `friend` declaration declares that a class of that name, *in the surrounding namespace*, is a friend, if such a class exists. So this is equivalent to

```
friend class GuiController::SceneEditorPluginWidgetController;
```

However, your comments say that the class is actually in the global namespace, not `GuiController`, so this doesn't make it a friend. You'll need to qualify it correctly:

```
friend class ::SceneEditorPluginWidgetController;
```

Comment: In case it may be useful to others, I also had to forward-declare the class in the appropriate namespace.